# How configure timeout for apache camel jetty component

Tags: apache-camel

I use Talend Open Studio 5.6 ESB, I make a apache camel route. The end of my route is :

```
.removeHeaders("CamelHttpPath")
.removeHeaders("CamelHttpUrl")
.removeHeaders("CamelServletContextPath")
.to("jetty:http://toOverRide?bridgeEndpoint=false&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&useContinuation=false&httpClient.timeout=120000&httpClient.idleTimeout=120000")
```

Before this, I overide the url in the jetty component for call a remote service. This service takes 30 seconds to reply, the route closes the connection and send a error 503. How can I increase the timeout.

log camel :

```
[WARN ]: org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet - Continuation expired of exchangeId: ID-A1995-62398-1480423883621-0-1
[WARN ]: org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet - Cannot resume expired continuation of exchangeId: ID-A1995-62398-1480423883621-0-1
```

reponse :

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 1325
Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 503</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /sync/mockTmcWithLog/utilisateurs/30000. Reason:
<pre>    Service Unavailable</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
.to("jetty:http://toOverRide?continuationTimeout=900000&httpClient.timeout=900000")
```