# configure continuation timeout in jboss fuse esb

Tags: apache-camel, jetty, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am using jboss fuse esb 6.2.0. I would like change the jetty continuation timeout at server level(i.e single configuration for all apis continuation timeout), can any one help me to do this. I tried a lot at the end I found setting at http endpoint level like one explained in [configure-timeout-for-apache-camel-jetty-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866535/how-configure-timeout-for-apache-camel-jetty-component).

Please find the jetty.xml configuration

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host">
                <Property name="jetty.host"/>
            </Set>
            <!-- We explicitly set port to 0 to avoid port conflicts, then a real port will be picked
                 from org.ops4j.pax.web pid, which is PortService aware
            -->
            <Set name="port">
                <Property name="jetty.port" default="0"/>
            </Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>

<Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService">
            <Set name="name">karaf</Set>
            <Set name="loginModuleName">karaf</Set>
            <Set name="roleClassNames">
                <Array type="java.lang.String">
                    <Item>org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal.RolePrincipal</Item>
                </Array>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

Comment: "jetty continuation timeout"?  are you referring to the old Continuation API that was replaced by Servlet 3.0 AsyncContext in Jetty 8?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, I am not aware about it. But, we are using jetty 8.

Comment: Just so you know, [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt redhat jboss fuse 6.2.0 is a integration tool, which uses camel-jetty where camel jetty internally uses jetty8 below i am sharing jetty.xml